# How to decode a jwt from azure active directory in kitura?

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory, kitura

I received an access token from azure ad and try to decode it on a kitura server.

On jwt.io i can decode it successfully but not via the jwt decode routines from kitura sample project. I am using the exact code given by the sample kitura project on github.
Has someone used that with an azure token?

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example token that you are trying to decode?
Are you hoping to validate the token or just decode it? 
Have you created a struct that models the claims you are hoping to decode from the JWT?

Comment: I'm not able to provide an example token. As I have seen decoding goes along with verifying in this sample. Both ways would be awesome. Do i have to completely model the token as a claim?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link to where you generated to token from?
You can use the `.none` verifier to skip verification of the token. This will allow you to tell if the issue is with verification or decoding the JWT. You can use the provided`ClaimsStandardJWT`  struct to decode standard claims. If you have any custom claims you want to decode then you need to model them in your own struct.

Comment: ok...it's an issue with the claim. 
I have a token similar to the sample v1 token from this site: [link to azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to decode the v1 token to a struct without verifying using the following code:

```
struct AzureJWTClaims: Claims {
    let aud: String
    let iss: String
    let iat: Date
    let nbf: Date
    let exp: Date
    let acr: String
    let aio: String
    let amr: [String]
    let appid: String
    let appidacr: String
    let email: String
    let family_name: String
    let given_name: String
    let idp: String
    let ipaddr: String
    let name: String
    let oid: String
    let rh: String
    let scp: String
    let sub: String
    let tid: String
    let unique_name: String
    let uti: String
    let ver: String
}
let jwt = try? JWT<AzureJWTClaims>(jwtString: "<YourJWTString>", verifier: .none)
```

If you want to verify the JWT as well you need to create a `JWTVerifier` from a PEM encoded RSA public key:

```
let verifier = JWTVerifier.rs256(publicKey: Data("<PEM public key>".utf8))
```

Then pass this to the decoder:

```
let verifiedJWT = try? JWT<AzureJWTClaims>(jwtString: "<YourJWTString>", verifier: verifier)
```

Comment: Decoding (even the example v1 string from ms docs) still returns nil.

Comment: I had to adjust the claim a bit but it finally worked! Thank you Matt and Andrew!